# Delaying or sorting REST API triggered outbound IVR calls outside of allowed TCPA time?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

We will be sending requests for outbound calls via REST API to Twilio Studio via batch each morning. However, the order in which they are sent is arbitrary, and some called parties will be in time zones in which, calls should not be made at that time (e.g. calling PST time zones at 8:00AM EST). How can we deal with this? I could put in a split based on the State, which would be known. However then what? Could I include a loop based on a time check? If so, it is conceivable that the number of called parties waiting for their time zone to become eligible would exceed the number of concurrent outbound calls which are allowed. Would this then prevent normally eligible calls from being placed, or do flow executions not count towards this limit unless a call has already been placed?

I had thought about storing the queued requests in Sync, and executing them based on the State criteria in conjunction with a time check function. However, I'm not sure if this would even work.

Is there some means of sorting, or otherwise selecting queued API requests based on a criteria?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The decision on when to place the call would be determined outside of Twilio.

You would first identify which timezone the customers are in and group those based on Pacific, Mountain, Central, Eastern, say using the address within your CRM - which is safer then using their area code.

Then, once the time is appropriate for that timezone, you would make a call to the Twilio Studio Executions end-point to place each of the calls.

You can monitor [queue_time](https://www.twilio.com/changelog/outbound-call-queue-insights-programmable-voice-rest-api) to determine how many milliseconds a call remains in the queue before being placed, in case you need to increase you CPS (or slow down your calling) and to avoid abnormally large queues resulting in calls placed outside allowed business hours.

So, in short, the queueing logic is handled on your side rather then on Twilio's side.

Answer (score 0):

Because of our specific use case, it is desirable to have the functionality self-contained. We prioritize inbound calls and the call volume varies, so the number of concurrent calls placed by the outbound IVR is very low. This means that a call can be queued for an extended period of time, and our allowed calling window may expire. Therefore, we must make this check immediately prior to making the attempt

I was able to resolve this with a function which checks the current time via a new Date().toISOString() and adds or subtracts the offset based on the time zone of the called party.

Comment: Please show the code here and explain it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).